# ability to read and write unicode data without adding any extra encoding

Tags: go

I have some EBCDIC mainframe data (non DBCS) that i am getting from a 3rd party utility that provides me data EBCDIC data in unicode. x'00' = \u0000, etc.  I am having a problem when the data starts coming across starting at \u0080.  When I convert this data into a byte array, I am getting 2 bytes instead of 1.  For example when I receive \u0080, in my byte array I am getting the 2 bytes 0xc2 0x80.  I only want my byte array to have 0x80.  Below is an example:

```
func allUnicode() (text string, bytes []byte, err error) {
    text = "\u0080\u0081\u0082\u0083\u0084\u0085\u0086\u0087\u0088\u0089\u008a\u008b\u008c\u008d\u008e\u008f\u0090\u0091\u0092\u0093\u0094\u0095\u0096\u0097\u0098\u0099\u009a\u009b\u009c\u009d\u009e\u009f\u00a0\u00a1\u00a2\u00a3\u00a4\u00a5\u00a6\u00a7\u00a8\u00a9\u00aa\u00ab\u00ac\u00ad\u00ae\u00af\u00b0\u00b1\u00b2\u00b3\u00b4\u00b5\u00b6\u00b7\u00b8\u00b9\u00ba\u00bb\u00bc\u00bd\u00be\u00bf\u00c0\u00c1\u00c2\u00c3\u00c4\u00c5\u00c6\u00c7\u00c8\u00c9\u00ca\u00cb\u00cc\u00cd\u00ce\u00cf\u00d0\u00d1\u00d2\u00d3\u00d4\u00d5\u00d6\u00d7\u00d8\u00d9\u00da\u00db\u00dc\u00dd\u00de\u00df\u00e0\u00e1\u00e2\u00e3\u00e4\u00e5\u00e6\u00e7\u00e8\u00e9\u00ea\u00eb\u00ec\u00ed\u00ee\u00ef\u00f0\u00f1\u00f2\u00f3\u00f4\u00f5\u00f6\u00f7\u00f8\u00f9\u00fa\u00fb\u00fc\u00fd\u00fe\u00ff"
    bytes = []byte(text)
    return
}
```

when i inspect the bytes array, i get 0xc2 0x80 ... My process has to parse this array based on position and those extra bytes throw everything off.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Strings in go are utf8, can you show what you expect the `bytes` to be after converting the string?

Comment: Maybe to put in another way, unicode codepoints can be larger than a single byte, so you can't convert this to `[]byte` without some sort of encoding.

Comment: I'm afraid your example _as presented_ may contain a bug: since `text` is a so-called string literal, those `\uXXXX` escape sequences are processed at the compilation phase, and at runtime `text` contains UTF-8 encoded data, with the results of expanding any `\uXXXX` representing code points besides the 7-bit ASCII range occupying more than a single byte each. This is basically what @JimB referred to. But since you say you're receiving the data from a third party, I doubt you receive from it Go string literals which you then _compile._ So let's try to come up with a more real MCVE.

Comment: Please read [this](https://blog.golang.org/strings) for an in-depth explanation of how strings work in Go, and how string literals in the source code files fit the picture.

Comment: after some more testing, i was able to change bytes = []byte(text) to bytes = []rune(text) and the conversion was successful.  I was able to see the data the way i expected.  checking now if my parser has any trouble processing this rune array

Comment: «…`bytes = []rune(text)` and the conversion was successful.»–please again note that while `[]byte(string)` merely copies memory verbatim, `[]rune(text)` pefroms full decoding of multi-byte sequences in UTF-8 encoding to Unicode code points they encode, merely reverting the effect of processing of `\uXXXX` in a string literal did by the compiler. I mean, you quite possibly are still dealing with a red herring. Maybe not, but please take what I'm saying seriously. The type-conversions of strings to slices of runes is covered in the text I gave link to earlier, as well.